# Webpack HMR Throws React syntheticEvent Error Due To jsPDF

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, jspdf, webpack-hmr

***SYSTEM INFO:***

```
OSX 10.12.4 Sierra
Node v7.10.0
npm v4.2.0
```

***BROWSERS TESTED:***

```
Chrome 58.0.3029.110
Safari 10.1
Firefox 53.0
```

***THE PROBLEM:***

I have an app running effectively in production that I've cloned and am attempting to update in preparation for building out a sequel. However, I've run into a strange Webpack issue by updating it / React / HMR to more recent builds.

The HMR will connect, and Webpack appears to compile just fine. However, interacting with the page *(such as clicking)* generates the following error:

[image: syntheticEvent Error]

Obviously, the app is at that point no longer functional as clicking things does not fire off anything. Interestingly, we also get the following 404 error in the Node console and on the browser:

[image: 404]
*(NOTE: this appears to be a giant query string incl functions, and specifically referencing syntheticEvent. I can print the whole thing for you if you want)*

**NODE v6.3.1**

**RELEVANT NPMs:**

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
"react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",

"webpack": "^2.5.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"

"babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
"babel-core": "^6.24.1",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
"babel-plugin-array-includes": "^2.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.0.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
```

**WEBPACK.CONFIG.DEV.JS:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var hotMiddlewareScript = 'webpack-hot-middleware/client';

console.log('using the dev config file');
console.log('THE PUBLIC PATH: ' + path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/static'));

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    background: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/components/background')],
    uniqueShare: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client',  path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/components/uniqueShare')],
    starRating: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/components/starRating')],
    testingPage: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/components/testingPage')],
    style: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/components/style')]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/CLIENTSIDE/static'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'],
              plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-object-assign', 'array-includes'],
            },
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

**WHERE WE LOAD UP HMR:**

```
  console.log('****************************** RUNNING IN DEV MODE ******************************');
  var webpack = require('webpack');
  var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.dev');
  var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  console.log('Looking for the HMR here: ' + webpackConfig.output.publicPath);

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
```

Now, here's the strange part. Babel / Webpack compile *everything* just fine in production mode, without the hot reloader. The app runs perfectly fine when we set the Node ENV to 'PRODUCTION' - no syntheticEvent errors.

Furthermore, the app runs in dev mode *(with hot reloading)* just fine using the previous stack, which includes the following NPM versions:

```
"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.0",
"react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.0",

"webpack": "^1.13.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"

"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
"babel-core": "^6.10.4",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.0.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.0.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.8",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.0.2",
```

***UPDATE 5/16/17:***

We've isolated the problem to migration from React / React DOM `0.14.8` to `v15.0.0`. Doing so **immediately** triggers our error - but ***only in HMR / Dev mode.***

The production build, without HMR, compiles just fine; referencing the minified files Webpack produces through that config lets the app function 100% normally.

The **exact same build** runs 100% fine in React / DOM `0.14.8`, in Dev mode, with HMR. Upgrading **ONLY** Webpack / HMR / webpack-hot-middleware to the latest versions does **NOT** trigger the error.

I spent some time digging into the debug panel and found the following:

[image: Clickeventobject]
*This is a decent glance at the actual event object being generated natively by React. In this case, a "topClick" that is not associated with any handlers we've created. I can literally fire this & the error by clicking anywhere on the page.*

[image: Where the error happens]
*This is the line where the error actually occurs. It's coming from react-dom/lib/SyntheticUIEvent.js - and appears to have failed to initialize a .call method on the SyntheticEvent class...*
[image]

It's also worth noting that the console also fires the following error **every time you reload**, first thing.

```
GET http://localhost:3333/[object%20Object]?url=function%20SyntheticEvent(dispa…d%20%3D%20emptyFunction.thatReturnsFalse%3B%0A%20%20return%20this%3B%0A%7D 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ jspdf.debug.js:17350
l @ jspdf.min.js:284
u @ jspdf.min.js:284
XHR @ jspdf.debug.js:17334
Proxy @ jspdf.debug.js:16928
(anonymous) @ SyntheticEvent.js:188
(anonymous) @ SyntheticEvent.js:268
(anonymous) @ background.js:805
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ SyntheticCompositionEvent.js:13
(anonymous) @ background.js:2110
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ BeforeInputEventPlugin.js:16
(anonymous) @ background.js:1767
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ ReactDefaultInjection.js:14
(anonymous) @ background.js:1963
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ ReactDOM.js:16
(anonymous) @ ReactDOM.js:111
(anonymous) @ background.js:1844
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ index.js:3
(anonymous) @ background.js:812
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ background.js:9
(anonymous) @ background.js:3178
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
fn @ background.js:86
(anonymous) @ background:2
(anonymous) @ background.js:3287
__webpack_require__ @ background.js:658
(anonymous) @ background.js:707
(anonymous) @ background.js:710
```

**The same error from the Node console:**

```
GET /[object%20Object]?url=function%20SyntheticEvent(dispatchConfig%2C%20targetInst%2C%20nativeEvent%2C%20nativeEventTarget)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(process.env.NODE_ENV%20!%3D%3D%20%27production%27)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20these%20have%20a%20getter%2Fsetter%20for%20warnings%0A%20%20%20%20delete%20this.nativeEvent%3B%0A%20%20%20%20delete%20this.preventDefault%3B%0A%20%20%20%20delete%20this.stopPropagation%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20this.dispatchConfig%20%3D%20dispatchConfig%3B%0A%20%20this._targetInst%20%3D%20targetInst%3B%0A%20%20this.nativeEvent%20%3D%20nativeEvent%3B%0A%0A%20%20var%20Interface%20%3D%20this.constructor.Interface%3B%0A%20%20for%20(var%20propName%20in%20Interface)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!Interface.hasOwnProperty(propName))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(process.env.NODE_ENV%20!%3D%3D%20%27production%27)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20delete%20this%5BpropName%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20has%20a%20getter%2Fsetter%20for%20warnings%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20normalize%20%3D%20Interface%5BpropName%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(normalize)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5BpropName%5D%20%3D%20normalize(nativeEvent)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(propName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27target%27)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.target%20%3D%20nativeEventTarget%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5BpropName%5D%20%3D%20nativeEvent%5BpropName%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20var%20defaultPrevented%20%3D%20nativeEvent.defaultPrevented%20!%3D%20null%20%3F%20nativeEvent.defaultPrevented%20%3A%20nativeEvent.returnValue%20%3D%3D%3D%20false%3B%0A%20%20if%20(defaultPrevented)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.isDefaultPrevented%20%3D%20emptyFunction.thatReturnsTrue%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.isDefaultPrevented%20%3D%20emptyFunction.thatReturnsFalse%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20this.isPropagationStopped%20%3D%20emptyFunction.thatReturnsFalse%3B%0A%20%20return%20this%3B%0A%7D 404 4.745 ms - 35162
```

Comment: **UPDATE:** 
Upon further digging, it appears that the upgrade to React v15+ is what breaks things - but I'm not at all sure why. v14.8 works just fine, and it does **not** appear that any changes to implementing HMR via Webpack 2 / webpack-hot-middleware have occurred

_this is our hot reload handler in react:_
`if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}`

Comment: can you share the code where this error is being originated? where you are using the event object? are you trying to use the event object in some sort of async operation?

Comment: I don't think it is caused by react upgrade alone.  The error basically means a click event object is passed to one of your function which expects it to have a `call` method. You have to show the code that throws the exception and all the *change* of your package.json

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys! I'd really like to give you the code which is breaking things - but we literally have no idea where it is. We're not manually using any event objects - just basic handler functions. Simple.

What we do know is that we've isolated it to moving from React / DOM 14.8 to 15.0 - doing so **immediately** triggers the error and _only_ in HMR / dev mode. There is **no specific component that fires the error,** clicking anywhere at all on the landing page fires it off.... I don't understand how the production build can compile without firing the same error

Comment: Updated OP to reflect most recent info.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I stepped through some dev environment maintenance today, and did a `brew doctor`, `brew uninstall --force node`, `brew install node`, `brew link node --overwrite` and `brew prune` - cleaned up everything there. 
I also switched dependency management over to `yarn` and rebuilt `node_modules`. Still no luck same errors occurring. Will update OP with system info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 5/24/17:**

*We finally figured out the issue - a classic mistake!*

After retooling our entire stack to be more in line with `create-react-app`, I migrated our prior React app into the dev server Index file. Worked as expected, albeit without the right HTML wrapping and styles etc.

However, when I migrated the full HTML page to which we render out the app to a `<div id="root>` element, it started spitting out the SyntheticEvent error again! A lot of work and restructuring finally isolated the problem to the HTML file *(which, realistically, was actually an EJS file originally and mostly contains a basic skeleton as well as SEO tracking)*

**Here's the rub:** we had an outdated `<script/>` tag that was calling out to `jsPDF v1.2.61` *(https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)*. We **are no longer actually using this plugin** and the script appears to have snuck its way back in to our code due to a merge conflict.

In retrospect, the code posted in the OP *does* reference the jsPDF plugin, but the stack trace doesn't really provide any indication of where the error originates. Because we literally haven't touched the plugin since the very beginning of the app, and pursued an alternative approach, the name didn't ring any bells - given the later calls to React's scripts, I simply assumed the first three or so lines of the stack trace indicated jspdf was some obscure part of the React library.

*THERE ARE TWO FIXES TO THIS ISSUE:*

1. **Remove the script entirely -** this is what we did, as we no longer are using jsPDF in our application.
2. **Update jsPDF -** the plugin is now at `v1.3.4`. The prior version, `v1.2.61`, ***generates a breaking conflict*** with `React v15.0.0+` native library scripts. The new version **DOES NOT** generate conflicts.

Hopefully this will help somebody down the road!

***Reference only; prior solution that did not work and tipped us off to the fix above:***

In order to move our project forward, we've opted for an alternative stack using `create-react-app` and `custom-react-scripts`.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts

Ultimately, we are *(loosely)* following this pattern to run the CRA Stack alongside our Node / Express stuff concurrently:
https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/

At the end of the day, this accomplishes our goal of pushing the new stack into up-to-date technologies. And, it's probably a little cleaner than what we were running before.

However, I am still *completely* mystified as to the origin of the error above. I've moved stuff around in a bunch of other test stacks and can't seem to replicate the issue w/`Webpack 2` and `React 15+` - and there's nothing fundamentally different about the way I am setting them up from our original stack.

Whatever is going on, it's very strange.